# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'datepicker' of null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

**Inline javascript.** It should be a **js conflict issue** as all of javascripts work if separately.
[source page](http://rentbudapestapartments.com)

```
$(function () {
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: "today",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#leaving ").change(function () {
        var d = j$(this).val();
        if (d) $("input#arriving ").datepicker("option ", "minDate ", d);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have two references to jQuery. Remove the second reference. (http://www.rentbudapestapartments.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3)

Comment: It doesn't work. My problem I also use prototype library which uses $ variable. I would like override the $ variable for this short code above. How to do this?

Comment: You should probably take a look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is included twice:

First at line 36 in source:

```
36: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.rentbudapestapartments.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

Second on line 58 in source:

```
58: <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

The second is probably from a template you borrowed or automatic from WordPress. I'd drop the first one on line 36 if you have control of it.

Also on this line

```
var d = j$(this).val();
```

what is `j$`? It's probably supposed to be `$(this).val()`

Comment: I replaced j$ with $ as suggested and deleted line 36, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input regarding the script called twice. This may cause problems.
I solved this cas by **renaming the $ variable to avoid js conflicts**.

```
<script>
var abc = $;
$(function() {
abc("input.datepicker").datepicker({minDate:"today", dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = $;
$(document).ready(function()
{
abc("input#leaving").change(function()
{
var d = abc(this).val();
if(d)abc("input#arriving").datepicker("option","minDate",d);
}
);
});
</script>
```

This works for me!